cannot make C++ stdout flush
I'm a beginner at C++, and was thinking of starting an app that integrates lua as an extension language.  I copied the bare-bones REPL code below from somewhere and lightly adapted it to C++, but "at end", and "fprintf at end", do not appear when I run in release mode after I terminate input with Ctrl+D, despite my multiple flush call variants, but do appear when I run in debug mode, even without any breakpoints.  It's a rather demoralizing start to what should be the easy part; what am I missing?  I am running on MacOs in CLion with the clang toolchain provided by XCode if it matters.
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "at beginning" << std::endl;
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        const char *cLine = line.c_str();
        int error = luaL_loadstring(L, cLine) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
        if (error) {
            const char *luaOut = lua_tostring(L, -1);
            std::cerr << luaOut << std::endl;
            lua_pop(L, 1);
        } else {
            std::cout << "output above a result of evaluating: ["
                      << line
                      << "]"
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }
    lua_close(L);
    std::cout << "at end" << std::endl;
    fprintf(stdout, "fprintf at end\n");
    std::flush(std::cout);
    std::cout.flush();
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(NULL);
    return 0;
}

example session below:
at beginning
print(2 ** 3)
[string "print(2 ** 3)"]:1: unexpected symbol near '*'
print(2 ^ 3)
8.0
output above a result of evaluating: [print(2 ^ 3)]
print("hope this works, too")
hope this works, too
output above a result of evaluating: [print("hope this works, too")]
^D

Update
If I comment out the loop, the std::cout statements at the end work as expected.  If I comment out the body of the loop, but leave the for statement intact, the std::cout statements after the loop do not work.
Second Update
After running from the terminal and seeing everything work, and reading the comments below, it seems that problem is not with the C++ code, but CLion.  I am adding the CLion tag.  If I cannot find a solution to this very worrying problem I will abandon CLion, which is disappointing as I like all the other JetBrains IDE's a lot.

Add more std::cout output inside the loop. Print the values of line, cLine and error. Add quotes around string output to see if there are unexpected spaces.

If the program does not stop working if you press ctrl-d, where is it spending its time? Attach a debugger to it and break.

Stick to C++ I/O, avoid the f* functions. If the first flush (<< std::endl;) doesn't work, adding four more flushes will not help.

Does it work if you remove all the Lua stuff?

On the advice of @Someprogrammerdude I added outputs within the loop.  I should have made clear in the original post that lua was not the problem-- it is evaluating and printing the results I would expect.

@molbdnilo Yes, it does work when I remove the lua includes and lua code, so what is left is just std::cout calls plus std::cout.flush()

@Botje That's the thing: the program does stop when I press Ctrl+D, and, as far as I can tell, all the code after the loop runs, it just doesn't output anything, except when I run in debug mode, even without any breakpoints.  This is like the Heisenberg uncertainty principle-- adding a debugger and observing what is going on has the effect of fixing everything.

Cannot reproduce this on my mac. I built your code with plain g++ and it always prints the "at end" messages for me.

Are you running from inside of Clion? Have you tried running it yourself in an independent terminal? Clion have had problems in the past to actually flush output when you run from inside of Clion.

@Someprogrammerdude Yes, I was running this from within CLion.  When I run it from a terminal I get normal output.

@SourceSimian So I would just label that CLion thing as "garbage" -- or maybe it doesn't support Ctrl-D, or uses something else to indicate EOF.

@ChristianStieber Ctrl+D is working.  It closes the input and ends the program with an exit code of 0; the problem appears to be CLion not picking up the output of the program correctly.  Doing some research, it seems to be an old and ongoing problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5704

It turns out this was not a problem with the code in any iteration.  The problem is that CLion has an old and unfixed bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5704
Disabling run.processes.with.ptty gave me the output I expected.
